# How to store exact decimal value in Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to store `145.19064169678300` decimal value in database but when I look into database the last 3 digits are different and stored value is `145.19064169678299`. My migration file looks like this

```
  t.decimal :latitude, null: false, precision: 18, scale: 15
```

For value `145.449895817713000` it is stored as `145.449895817713013`

How can I store the exact value without any rounding ? I am using postgres as database.

Comment: @dbugger so how can i store `145.19064169678300` exactly as it is ?

Comment: @dbugger i am saving data by reading CSV file and creating new object in seed.rb file. Also updated the question.

Comment: @dbugger you are correct. Excel was rounding it. It was looking into Excel and comparing it. Please post it as your answer and i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you viewing the csv file in Excel?

Are you sure Excel isn't rounding the display?

Excel, in its attempts to be "helpful" can distort the display of data, and change the underlying data if you edit the file.  It drops leading 0s, rounds numbers or converts them to scientific notation. Best to stick with plain text editors when working with CSV or TSV files.